# Ideal of affine algebraic variety is radical

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

In remark 1.15(c) of [these notes](http://www.mathematik.uni-kl.de/~gathmann/class/alggeom-2014/chapter-1.pdf) by Gathman, it is said that for a ring $R$, an ideal of an affine variety is radical, for if $f\in \sqrt I$ then $f^k|_X=0$ and hence $f|_X=0$ meaning $f\in I$. I'm confused. If "ideal of an affine algebraic variety $X$" just means an ideal of $R$ which is a subset of $X$, then why would it be radical if $R$ is not reduced?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the affine variety $X \subset \Bbb{A}^n$ is defined by an ideal $J \subset k[x_1 , \dots , x_n] $, then the ideal of $X$ is not necessarily $J$.

The ideal of $X$ is by definition something else, namely
$$I(X)= \{ f \in k[x_1 , \dots , x_n] : f|_X = 0\}$$
which turns out to be an ideal containing the ideal $J$. The fact that $I(X)$ is a radical ideal does not mean that $J$ is a radical ideal.

EDIT: Here is the proof. Let $f^k \in I(V(J))$: we want to prove that $f \in I(V(J))$. At every point $p \in V(J)$ you have
$$f^k(p)=(f(p))^k=0$$
but $k$ is a field, in particular it is a reduced ring. Hence
$$f(p)=0$$
by arbitrarity of $p$ you have that $f \in I(V(J))$.

Comment: But doesn't this use the Nullstellensatz? The remark is stated for a ring, and precedes the Nullstellensatz in the notes..

Comment: No, Nullstellensatz only states that, if $k$ is algebraically closed, then $I(V(J)) = \sqrt{J}$ (which is a radical ideal containing $J$). Now, in general, $I(V(J))$ is a radical ideal containing $J$, but it could be anything.

Comment: Okay, I can think of some examples where the containment is strict, but I'm not sure how to prove it is always a radical ideal. I think the idea is that the zero locus of a polynomial and all its powers is the same, but I don't know how to make this into a proof..

Comment: Okay so you are indeed assuming $R$ to be reduced, which is not assumed in the notes.

Comment: @Exterior Yes it is!—1.15.c implicitly takes $R$ to be a polynomial ring: the notes define an affine variety to be a subset $X\subset \mathbb{A}^n$ defined by some polynomials, and the ideal $I(X)\subset K[x_1,\ldots ,x_n]$ to be the polynomials that vanish on $X$.  In this context, $R=K[x_1,\ldots ,x_n]$.

Comment: @Slade I didn't know we only look at polynomial rings with coefficients in a field :(

Comment: @Exterior $K$ isn't just a field, it's an algebraically closed field, which is required to prove the Nullstellensatz.  There is a theory of algebraic geometry over general rings: For example, if $V(J)$ is the set of prime ideals in $R$ containing $J$, then $I(V(J))$, the ideal of elements contained in each prime ideal, does equal $\sqrt{J}$.  But this is not discussed in these notes.

Comment: @Slade Crostul mentions in the comments the algebraic closedness is not needed for $\mathbf I\mathbf V(I)$ to be radical, only equal to $\sqrt I$.

Comment: In your proof, why does one need to assume that X itself is a affine variety? Couldn' t it just by any set X⊂An, since f evaluates zero on X it automatically must be in I(X)?

Answer (score 1):

Let $X \subset A^n$ be an affine variety. Then the ideal of $X$, denoted $I_X$, is its vanishing ideal, i.e. the set of all polynomials that vanish on $X$. This ideal is radical: Suppose $f \in \sqrt{I_X}$. Suppose for the sake of contradiction that $f \not\in I_X$. Hence there exists some $x \in X$ such that $f(x) \neq 0$. On the other hand $f^\ell \in I_X$ for some $\ell$, and so $f(x)^\ell = 0$. Now $f(x) \in k$, $k$ being the underlying field. Since any field is an integral domain, induction gives $f(x)=0$, which is a contradiction. Hence $f \in I_X$.

By the context of Remark 1.15(c) in the referred notes, i suppose that Gathman means that $R$ is the polynomial ring, since $I$ is the ideal of an affine variety and such an ideal lives (up to isomorphism) in a polynomial ring.

Comment: This also assumes $R$ is reduced, which is not mentioned in the notes. I take it the claim just isn't true unless this is the case.

Comment: @Exterior: I took a look at the remark you are referring to. I am pretty sure that the way to read it is "if $I$ is the ideal of a variety $X$ ( hence $R=k[y_1,\dots,y_n]$ the polynomial ring), then $I$ is radical."

Comment: I did not know algebraic geometry only looks at polynomial rings with coefficients in a field :(

Comment: @Exterior: Yes, that's the case, at least at the "basic" level. Moreover the field is usually assumed to be algebraically closed.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification!

Comment: You are welcome :)